# Is it possible to use nodes as anchors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, chemfig

I'm trying to recreate [a rather complicated reaction scheme](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Cysteinprotease_Reaktionsmechanismus.svg) with chemfig and TikZ. For that, I'd like to position several amino acid side chains at specific positions.

What I'd like to do is to use the "origins" of those side chains as anchors for positioning the molecules:

[image: MWE]

I cannot use normal anchors, however, as the origins' coordinates change depending on the molecules' bounding boxes. Additionally, the chemfig manual states that the origins' coordinates are only calculated when the molecule is actually placed with `\chemfig`.

So I thought about using chemfig's `@` syntax to place a node (called `ori`) at the origin and moving the chemfig molecule to it, using the `ori1`/`ori2` nodes as anchors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
  Cysteine side chain

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,anchor=south west] (cys) at (0,0) {\chemfig{-[@{ori1,0}2]S-H}};
    % ??? movement code ???
  \end{tikzpicture}

  Cysteine side chain, deprotonated

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, anchor=south west] (cys_deprot) at (0, 0) {\chemfig{-[@{ori2,0}2]S|^{-}}};
    % ??? movement code ???
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, as far as I've understood from reading through the TikZ manual, there is no way to use other nodes as anchors. Is there some way to achieve this?

Edit for clarification:

Let's talk about the first structure only, the other one is just for comparision. I'd like to use the bullet in the picture (node `ori1`) as the anchor of the rectangle (node `cys`). However, `ori1`'s coordinates are not known until `cys` is actually placed, which is why I believe I have to do the following dance:

1. Place the `cys` node, so that the `ori1` node gets defined:

   ```
   \node (cys) at (0,0) {\chemfig{-[@{ori1,0}2]S-H}};
   ```
2. Move `cys` to its new (fixed) position, anchored at `ori1`'s coordinates (this is the step I don't know).

Is this clear enough? If not, then I'll try and add a picture tonight.

Comment: Yes you can use nodes and their anchors in the process of positioning something else … can you translate your question for non-chemist? What is your goal, graphically?

Comment: You can’t position a node containing something else (in this case a TikZ picture itself) on a reference point of “something else” (however, you can affect the vertical placement with the `baseline` option). And you can’t move the parent node later. You can however use the coordinate `ori1` to place something else there. It is still unclear what you actually want to achieve? Remember that the result of `\chemfig` is in its own a TikZ picture. In the manual of `chemfig`, take a look at the `\chemmove` macro where you can reference the named coordinates and nodes with the `@` syntax.

Comment: The complete scheme of the picture you've linked can be set without too much trouble with `chemfig`'s scheming commands. I just played a bit and already set half the scheme... if you like I can post this as an answer although strictly speaking it may not be an answer...

Comment: @runiq here it is, in case you're interested: https://www.writelatex.com/read/sjfshknptmnq

Comment: BTW: do you know this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40695/chemfig-and-lego-style-molecule-construction

Comment: @cgnieder care for a simple answer?

Comment: @percusse I have no answer for the actual question and the OP never responded to my question regarding the scheme so I'm a bit reluctant...

Comment: @cgnieder If you cannot answer it we definitely cannot :)